# PDI fail on reading remote and compressed files

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

My problem is when I am reading a remote and compressed file from S3, a zip file to be specific. The file is not corrupted and sometimes a get an exception and sometimes no.

I found a similar problem in this old bug still open http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-1800

This is the error that is happening. I am running this transformation on a carte server. This error is not easy to reproduce, then, unfortunately, I do not have a recipe to reproduce it.

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleFileException:
Exception reading line: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.text.TextFileInputUtils.getLine(TextFileInputUtils.java:326)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.text.TextFileInputReader.tryToReadLine(TextFileInputReader.java:420)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.text.TextFileInputReader.readRow(TextFileInputReader.java:167)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.BaseFileInputStep.processRow(BaseFileInputStep.java:205)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
at org.pentaho.di.core.compress.CompressionInputStream.read(CompressionInputStream.java:68)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:127)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.text.TextFileInputUtils.getLine(TextFileInputUtils.java:294)
… 5 more
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleFileException:
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 –
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – Exception reading line: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 –
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 –
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.text.TextFileInputUtils.getLine(TextFileInputUtils.java:326)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.text.TextFileInputReader.tryToReadLine(TextFileInputReader.java:420)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.text.TextFileInputReader.readRow(TextFileInputReader.java:167)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.BaseFileInputStep.processRow(BaseFileInputStep.java:205)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at org.pentaho.di.core.compress.CompressionInputStream.read(CompressionInputStream.java:68)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:127)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.fileinput.text.TextFileInputUtils.getLine(TextFileInputUtils.java:294)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – S3CsvInput.0 – … 5 more
child index = 56, logging object : org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject@46345a23 parent=1ff32099-5cbe-47b3-b32c-34f1291f6c09
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – md5_field12308.0 – Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=391170, W=782340, U=0, E=0)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – Filter Rows field12308.0 – Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=3, W=3, U=0, E=0)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – Filter Rows field12315.0 – Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=13, W=13, U=0, E=0)
2017/12/13 12:07:40 – TransLoad_cube5403_data137170 – ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
```

Comment: I used to have similar problems, may be aren't you using the same file while downloading it? Most of the times, when you are writing the file you are processing, you get those stranges behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be a network issue; the file isn't fully downloaded and therefore it doesn't terminate properly.

Try downloading first and reading from a local file and see if the problem persists.